# stroke-dashoffset работает некорректно

Tags: css, svg, анимация

Есть побочный эффект, после выполнения `<animate/>` происходит заполнение каждой буквы цветом `stroke`, в Firefox такое не наблюдается. В чём может быть проблема?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <symbol id="stroke-dash">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Stroke</text>
  </symbol> 
  <use xlink:href="#stroke-dash" stroke="#9575cd" stroke-dasharray="70 250" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-size="4em">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="-320" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверил несколько версий. одна из них была известная особенность команды `<use>`,
после использования которой. `svg` объекты попадают в так называемый `Shadow DOM` и без принятия специальных действий плохо стилизуются.

- Для проверки максимально упростил анимацию, но баг в `Chrome`
  остался.  Такое впечатление, что атрибуты анимации -
  `stroke-dashoffset` и `stroke-dasharray` начинают давать сбои при
  резком увеличении параметров.
- Посмотрел несколько своих аналогичных работ, которые были созданы год
  назад и которые прекрасно работали, так и там наблюдается та же
  картина. Окрашивание целиком букв в цвет строки.

**Вывод однозначный,- это баг `Chrome`**
 Остается только ждать, когда разработчики устранят этот баг.

*В дополнение несколько примеров, которые работают, но немного с другим визуальным эффектом*

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%"  font-size="4em" stroke="#9575cd"  stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15 5"  stroke-dashoffset="250" >Stroke 
   
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="250;0;0;250;250" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Во втором примере анимации

- Сначала анимируется `stroke-dashoffset`
- После окончания первой анимации запускается вторая анимация
  `stroke-dasharray` команда на запуск -`begin="anOffset.end"`
- Затем идёт переход к первой анимации

`begin="0s;anArray.end"`

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%"  font-size="100px" stroke="violet"  stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20 10 5 5"  stroke-dashoffset="250" >Stroke 
   
     <animate id="anOffset" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s;anArray.end" values="250;0;250" dur="5s" repeatCount="1"/> 
 <animate id="anArray" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="anOffset.end" values="0;250;0" dur="10s" repeatCount="1"/> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, Александр, ну хоть успокоил:))
Заслуженный `checkbox` & `plus` за труд

Comment: Я тоже думал, что это баг, придётся делать анимацию твоим способом, что-то забыл про него, спасибо ещё раз

Comment: @St1myL не за что :)